# Docusign Authorization Code Grant without a login

Tags: php, laravel, docusignapi

I have created a property dealer website in PHP(laravel), there will be agents registration with DocuSign signature agreement, of-course all agents have not an access of login so how will be authorized the agent without a login to get access token for taking an agreement signature, sorry for my bad English and thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asher, you may want to look into JWT tokens. These can be used without login, but they must impersonate an actual user for the purpose of making API calls. you have to choose that user and find the userId to make these calls.
You can find the php example for JWT auth here - https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-php-jwt. I recommend you try this code, see how it works and take it from there.

Comment: i  followed the example but get invalid_grant error

ds_config.ini
`DS_CLIENT_ID="Inregerator key"
DS_IMPERSONATED_USER_GUID="GUID Id"
SIGNER_EMAIL="signer email"
SIGNER_NAME="signer name"
DS_PRIVATE_KEY="RSA keypair private key with quotes"
DS_AUTH_SERVER="https://account-d.docusign.com"
DS_TARGET_ACCOUNT_ID="8454237"
 `
**Link**
http://demowebdesignservices.com/docusign-jwt/main.php

Comment: Asher, how did you set your integration key?

Comment: yup, well i setup again from zero ,now program is working well,thank you